# Find no of Set of Unique Combination

Tags: combinations

I need a formula for following problem.
We have 3 objects A B and C. We can create a set of **two distinct object** (eg. AB AC BA order doesn't matter). 
Now we have 5 A objects, 3 B objects, 2 C objects.
Then how many set can we have?

**Ans:** 5 Sets

**One More Example:**
A: 2
B: 2
C: 2

**Ans:** 3 Sets

I need a general formula to implement it in a software, where it will take 3 parameter

No of A: X

No of B: Y

No of C: Z

and give the output.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Can you edit to specify what the 5 sets are for the 5A, 3B, 2C case.

Answer (score 0):

The number of sets will be $10!/5!.3!.2!$ sets as we  have 5  A objects 3B objects and 2 C objects.Hope this helps you.

Comment: Note the answer is for a pair.

Comment: no the ans should be 5.

Comment: I am not getting your logic.

Comment: Can you ellaborate more on this.